# What is my system's target triplet?

Tags: c, linux, build, system, target

On my netbook, `gcc -dumpmachine` is giving me `i686-linux-gnu`, but `clang -dumpmachine` is giving me `i386-pc-linux-gnu`. On my laptop, I get
`x86_64-linux-gnu` with gcc and `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` on clang.

I'm working with a more or less generic build script (works with multiple compilers) and I'd like to use the [target triplet](https://wiki.osdev.org/Target_Triplet) to determine installation directories, but they shouldn't change from compiler to compiler.

How can I "ID" the C "platform" I'm on in compiler-independent way?

Comment: does `uname` give you what you need?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Looks like it could. Thanks!